# import error in python script

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

I have this directory structure:

```
- program/
 -  --manage_dataset/
 -  ----__ init__.py
 -  ----dir1/
 -  ------__ init__.py
 -  ----dir2
 -  ------__ init__.py
 -  ----create_patch.py
 -  --test/
 -  ---- __ init__.py
 -  ----launcher.py
```

in laucher i need to use a function of create_patch.py so i put :

```
import manage_dataset.create_patch
```

in my ide (pycharm) work well but when I execute with terminal i have this error:

```
ImportError: No module named manage_dataset.create_patch
```

I tried to inser

```
sys.path.insert(0,path_to_program/manage_dataset)
```

but nothing change...

Comment: after `sys.path.insert(0,'/path_to_program/manage_dataset')` just `import create_patch`

Comment: don't work: NameError: global name 'manage_dataset' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment use `import create_patch` after adding to `sys.path`
In directory /home/rolf/program/manage_dataset there is a python program called `create_patch.py`

```
def print_patch_id():
    print "Printed from create_patch.py"
```

Accessing it is as follows from my /home/rolf directory:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0,'/home/rolf/program/manage_dataset')
>>> import create_patch as cr_pat
>>> cr_pat.print_patch_id()
Printed from create_patch.py
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to install module first by pip.(I haven't tested it because I don't have access to install any modules)

```
pip install manage_dataset.create_patch
```

With next command you can see if module was installed.

```
pip freeze  | grep manage_dataset.create_patch
```

Comment: where I should install it? if i type: pip install manage_dataset.create_patch i have this error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement manage_dataset.create_patch (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for manage_dataset.create_mega_patch

Comment: If you are using unix/Linux terminal then you could use above commands, else use following link for installing a package in pycharm https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html Let me know it goes then.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding: I code the directory manage_dataset myself... sorry my bad... i want use function that are in create_pacht and that I implemented in my script named laucher.py

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the error you are seeing.

[image: Error with pip install]

This is because that package is not available with pip and is not maintained at pypi.python.org.

I tried googling for that package and I couldn't find it anywhere. Are you sure that's the package that you're looking for? Can you go to the place where you found that package and see how to get that? If they provide you a .whl file, download that file and install that package with pip with `pip install <package name>.`

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding: I code the directory manage_dataset myself... sorry my bad... i want use function that are in create_pacht and that I implemented in my script named laucher.py